# Manipulating multiple files with same name

Tags: unix, append, mv

I am trying to move about 1000 files that all begin with "simulation." into one directory entitled "simulations." I am using a remote server, and the files are currently in my home directory on the server. I need to move them to a separate directory because I need to, ultimately, append all the "simulation." files into one file. Is there a way to either append only the files in my home directory that begin with "simulation." or move only these files into a new directory? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can change directories to the desired path on the remote server... and the simulations are located in /currentPath  ... then....

```
cd desiredPath 

mkdir simulations 

mv /currentPath/simulation* simulations
```

(to futher answer your question... if you wanted to append all the files together, you could type `cat simulation* > allSimulations.txt`

Comment: Thank you for your help!